# Worksheet opens with no ribbon, File->Options disabled

Tags: excel-2013, ribbonx

I received a workbook to work on that opens with no ribbon,except of the File menu.
In the **File** menu, **Options** is disabled.
I looked over the code, but didn't find anything that can explain this. 
In **Workbook_open** I put **Stop** before the first line of execution but the menu is already gone,, 

Most appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answare [here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202.aspx)

In the section `To customize the Fluent UI by using Office Open XML Formats files`
I found the instructions how to control Ribbon UI XML file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Custom UI editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)?

Open your file in the editor and see if any changes to the UI have been made in the workbook. Remove any XML in the file to reset the customizations - just right-click the `customUI14.xml`-node (or similar) in the tree view and click **Remove**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm behind a heavy security policy, so I cannot run setups, unless from well known providers, so until now I couldn't check.
It seems to be a Microsoft tool, is there a direct link to the tool on MS sites?